# Matplotlib legend too wide

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am plotting a graph with six curves, where each curve has a label. The legend is placed below the graph, but it's wider than the figure. Please see code and screenshot.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.subplot(111)

for i in xrange(6):
    ax.plot(x, i * x, label='long_long_name = %ix$' % i)

#ax.legend()
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
              fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=3)
fig.tight_layout(rect=[0, 0.1, 1, 0.95])
plt.show()
```

How to configure the proper graph and legend size/position?
I looked at [Legend Guide](http://matplotlib.org/users/legend_guide.html) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4700614/how-to-put-the-legend-out-of-the-plot), but couldn't figure out how to make the legend narrower.

Comment: Why not just specify `ncol=2`?

Comment: That actually worked well. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I would simply recommend you change either the legend font size or the plot figure size. For doing so:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(x_size, y_size))
```

Try using x_size = 8 and y_size = 5.

Or

```
ax.legend(loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.05),
          fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=3, fontsize = size)
```

Try using size = 8.

Comment: Font size = 8 is too small, but it's one solution though.

Comment: The size I've chosen is just a suggestion, maybe using both font size and figure size will give you even better results. Or just bigger sizes.